# After a suicide operation, is contract’s nonce reset to 0?

Tags: nonce, selfdestruct

Simple question, but I couldn’t find the answer in the yellow paper.

Is it reset to 0 or is it kept at the latest value before destruction ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> After a suicide operation, is contract’s nonce reset to 0 ?

It seems the answer is **yes**.

An easy way to verify such a statement is to find a suicided contract and query a node to check its nonce.

For example take this contract : https://etherscan.io/address/0x45bdac52403cf49f5e45bcb8b3ce71cf5f16ef14.

It has been destroyed at this transaction : https://etherscan.io/tx/0xffd55f831d443ac45c33fb22e1bc2c24a7de49e10c9bf2251a4e0e77b5940ed4.

We get the account nonce with web3js this way :

```
const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0x45bdac52403cf49f5e45bcb8b3ce71cf5f16ef14");
console.log("nonce : ",nonce);
```

It returns us 0.

Comment: Last question, is it reset after the message call or at the end of the transaction hash ?

Answer (score -1):

Ethereum addresses with a codesize > 0 should always have a nonce of zero, as the address it sits at is created deterministically from the transaction that adds the code (creates the contract), and not from a private key.  Thus the contract itself can never make transactions and its nonce can never be increased.

Nonces only increase with addresses that can make (sign) transactions

Comment: Incorrect.  Contract addresses start with a nonce of 1 since EIP 160.  Additionally the contract nonce is incremented each time it creates another contract (ref: yellow paper).