# Redeploy to same address using CREATE (not CREATE2) | aka does a nonce reset?

Tags: nonce, selfdestruct, create2, create

Let's say I am using a (Gnosis) Safe as my main deployer account (**`0xD1`**) to allow for use of `CREATE2` calls.

1. I use my main account, `0xD1`, to deploy a "*TempCreator*" contract (**`0xC2`**) using `CREATE2`.
2. I use the TempCreator, `0xC2`, to deploy the "*Target*" contract (**`0xC1`**) *using `CREATE`*.

   > `0xC1` address is derived from `nonce=1` and `address=0xC2`, right?
3. I call self destruct on `0xC2` (TempCreator).
4. I redeploy TempCreator at `0xC2` using CREATE2.

   > [The nonce of TempCreator, `0xC2`, is reset to 1, right?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76496/after-a-suicide-operation-is-contract-s-nonce-reset-to-0#98755)

**Question:** *What happens if I deploy a new contract from TempCreator using `CREATE`?*

1. *Will it overwrite the existing code at the same address of the existing Target contract, `0xC1`?*
2. *What if the newly deployed byte
   code isn't the same size, does anything remain (possible overflow
   code execution)?*

---

Explained again:

1. Start with `SC1` at address `0xD1`.
2. `SC1` deploys `SC2` using `CREATE2` to address `0xC2`.

   > `0xC2 ≈ 0xD1 + bytecode + salt`
3. `SC2` deploys `SC3`, using `CREATE` to address `0xC1`.

   > `0xC1 ≈ nonce:1 + 0xC2`
4. `SC2` calls self destruct.
5. `SC1` re-deploys `SC2-new` using `CREATE2` (to the same address: `0xC2`).

   > the nonce for `SC2-new` is reset to 1, correct?
6. `SC2-new` deploys `SC4` using `CREATE`.

***What happens next?!?** Does `SC4` overwrite `SC3` at address `0xC1`?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Can you overwrite or override an existing contract?

It's impossible to overwrite an existing contract in Ethereum. From [EIP-684](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/684):

> If a contract creation is attempted, due to either a creation
> transaction or the `CREATE` (or future `CREATE2`) opcode, and the
> destination address already has either nonzero nonce, or nonempty
> code, then the creation throws immediately, with exactly the same
> behavior as would arise if the first byte in the init code were an
> invalid opcode. This applies retroactively starting from genesis.

---

This answer essentially from [Can CREATE2 with the same salt override existing contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97340/can-create2-with-the-same-salt-override-existing-contract)

So please upvote @Dominic's answer too.

For trivia, the linked [EIP-684](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/684) was first written in 2017, but it was only spotted "missing" (formally) in 2023.

Comment: What if I self destruct `SC3` / `0xC1` first? Would I then be able to deploy new code to the same address, given this pattern?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it would work.  Also, in your question, instead of "is reset to 1", I think you mean "is reset to 0".